# Unable to remotely connect to SQL Server Docker container in SSMS after some time, requires container restart

Tags: sql-server, docker, database-connection

I have a setup where I deployed a SQL Server Docker container with bridge network settings. Initially, I was able to connect to the container remotely using SSMS without any issues.

Recently, I encountered a problem where I couldn't establish a remote connection to the SQL Server container in SSMS. Strangely, the Portainer status indicated that the container was running properly. However, my attempts to connect to the container using SSMS were unsuccessful.

To resolve the issue temporarily, I resorted to restarting the container. After the restart, I was able to connect to the SQL Server container in SSMS successfully.

Additional Information:

Docker version: 23.0.1

SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU15) (KB5008996)-Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

Operating system: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Before restarting the container, I performed the following troubleshooting steps:

Checked network connectivity to ensure that the necessary ports were open.
Verified the SSMS configuration and connection details to rule out any misconfigurations.
Examined the container logs for any potential errors or issues.

Request for Assistance:

I would appreciate any insights into the possible root cause of this issue and suggestions for further troubleshooting steps. Additionally, if anyone has encountered a similar problem and found a permanent solution, I would be grateful for any guidance provided.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: _Examined the container logs for any potential errors or issues._ This seems like the most important part. Were you getting any kind of messages in the log while trying to connect from remotely? If not then it seems like a Docker networking or host networking issue. Were you able to open a bash console to the container and use `sqlcmd -S localhost` to connect to it?